# Meteor routing & rendering error

Tags: javascript, meteor, iron-router

Getting a strange error in Meteor:

> Route dispatch never rendered. Did you forget to call this.next() in an onBeforeAction?

and none of the content is rendering when I sign in. The same codebase is working on my friend's machine which is another MacBook. It works fine from his code when he deploys then I pull his code and deploy the same code and it throw the same error. You can see for yourself here http://streetscenestest.meteor.com/  and the router.js is below.

How can I fix this? Any help greatly appreciated.

Here's my router.js:

```
Router.configure({
    layoutTemplate: 'layout',
});

Router.route('/', function() {
    this.render('home');
});

Router.route('/user/:_username', {
  name: 'user_profile',
  data: function() { return Meteor.user();} 
});

Router.route('/create', function() {
  this.render('createEvent');
});

Router.route('/insert', function() {
  this.render('insertEvent');
});

Router.route('/events/:name', {
  name: 'event',
  data: function() { return Events.findOne({name: this.params.name});}
});



Router.route('/useremail', function() {
    this.render('userEmail');
}, {
    name: 'userEmail'
});

Router._filters = {
  hasCompletedProfile: function() {
    if(!this.ready()) return;
    var user = Meteor.user();
    if (user && ! userProfileComplete(user)){
      this.render('userEmail');
    } else {
      this.next();
    } 
    this.next();
  }, 
}; 

filters = Router._filters;
Router.onBeforeAction(filters.hasCompletedProfile);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just do as it says and call `this.next()`:

```
Router._filters = {
  hasCompletedProfile: function() {
    if (this.ready()) {
      var user = Meteor.user();
      if (user && !userProfileComplete(user)){
        this.render('userEmail');
      }
    } 
    this.next();
  }, 
};
```

Comment: Still not working unfortunately. I worry it's something to do with my setup because the same code seems to work fine on my pal's laptop

Comment: And it works when your friend deploys the same code to streetscenes.meteor.com, but not when you do? As if your computer is changing the code?! Weird..